# iCloud sign out lost note recovery

Tags: icloud, data-recovery, notes.app, proxy

Bit of a long shot, I was connected to iCloud on my work mac and created some notes. Connecting to iCloud then became no longer allowed on my work proxy so I got a message to sign out. When I signed out it lost all the iCloud notes that (I assume) hadn't synced to the server (as they don't appear in iCloud on any other of my devices).

Will these exist anywhere on my disk or are they lost forever? Any ideas on recovery?

Comment: Is the Mac using Time Machine or any other backup solution?

Comment: afraid not, no.